# brownie test results in ValueError: sender account not recognized

Tags: ganache, brownie, ganache-cli

I am trying to run [curve finance's multi-rewards](https://github.com/curvefi/multi-rewards/commit/99995f90bd129bbe6b5a995daf6233fb79789e4e) test suite with `brownie test`, however, the tests fail with the following error:

```
accounts = <brownie.network.account.Accounts object at 0x103e0caf0>, alice = <Account '0x66aB6D9362d4F35596279692F0251Db635165871'>

    @pytest.fixture(scope="module")
    def base_token(accounts, alice):
>       token = ERC20()
E       ValueError: sender account not recognized

tests/conftest.py:24: ValueError
```

My environment is as follows:

```
Brownie v1.17.1
Python v3.9.6
Node v18.16.0
Ganache v7.0.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue as follows. The biggest issue is with `ganache`, the version of `brownie` that I am using appears incompatible with `ganache`, so I had to uninstall and downgrade to the older and deprecated `ganache-cli`, if you have `ganache` globally installed you'll have to first [uninstall it](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/blob/develop/UPGRADE-GUIDE.md#globally-installed):

```shell
npm uninstall --global ganache-cli ganache-core ganache
```

Then make sure you're on node 16(node 18 doesn't work) before installing install `ganache-cli`(you can use `nvm` to switch to node 16):

```shell
npm install --global ganache-cli@6.12.1
```

I also had to upgrade the `black` and `eth-brownie` dependency versions in the `requirements.txt` as follows:

```
black==21.9b0
brownie-token-tester==0.1.0
eth-brownie>=1.16.3
flake8==3.7.9
isort==4.3.21
```

Make sure to install the dependencies(preferably in a python virtual environment) and make sure that when running `brownie test` it lists the correct dependencies and versions:

```
================================================= test session starts =================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.6, pytest-6.0.1, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/usr/multi-rewards
plugins: eth-brownie-1.14.5, hypothesis-5.41.3, xdist-1.34.0, web3-5.11.1, forked-1.3.0
```